# How to use php to output this html code?

Tags: php, html, escaping, quoting

How to use php to output this html code?
The html code is this.

```
<a href="#false" onclick="load_page('piano_programs.php')">Piano Programs</a>
```

but I want to use php to show this code

```
$program_name = "piano_programs";
echo "<a href='#false' onclick="load_page('$program_name'.php)">Piano Programs</a>";
```

but.....doesn't work, any idea ,thanks

Comment: Step 1. Get an editor with syntax highlighting. Step 2. Learn basic PHP syntax.

Comment: As Enstage shows in their answer: if you have a string-literal and it has quotes inside of it, you need to escape them. This is because PHP can't tell if the quote (a) is a quote or (b) the end of the string-literal.

Answer (score 2):

Backslashes to escape the quotes:

```
echo "<a href='#false' onclick=\"load_page('piano_programs.php')\">Piano Programs</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add slashes before onclick's two double quotes and move your single quote to the right side of `.php`.

```
echo "<a href='#false' onclick=\"load_page('{$program_name}.php')\">Piano Programs</a>";
```

I like to curly-bracket my variables so that they stand out in my editor and so that they don't get mixed up with the text that immediately follows.